# Pros and cons of the Access database engine. Life after SQLite

Tags: c#, vb6, ms-jet-ace

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482431/which-local-database-fits-my-situation) a while ago about which local DB was right for my situation.  I needed to access the DB from both .NET code and VB6.  The overwhelming response was SQLite.  However, I decided to pass on SQLite, because the only OLE DB provider for it charges royalties for every deployed copy of my software.  It also requires an activation procedure to be run on every single PC.

After evaluating other options (SQL Server Compact edition - barely functional OLE DB provider, Firebird - don't want to have to pay for another driver, etc...), I've come to conclusion that the only viable choice is using .MDB files created by Microsoft Access (or the Jet engine).

I haven't used it since late 90s, so I have the following questions to those who have experience with it.

1. Have they resolved the problem where the database would corrupt every now and then.
2. Is access to the MDB from c# accomplished via the ADO.NET OLEDB Provider or is there a native solution (i can't seem to find it).
3. Is there a viable alternative to the really crappy SQL Editor in Access?

Thanks.

Comment: I have had a number of small access application in use by a number of clients for quite a number of years and can only recall two instances of corruption so far, one very minor, one less so, both recoverable. It is a matter of setting it up properly: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-25.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather then going "back" to Access, I'd stick with SQLite and use the System.Data.SQLite provider for SQLite data access within the .NET code.

Then I'd just create a simple COM interop .NET class for use by VB6 that wraps any required SQLite data access functionality.  Finally, just reference and use it like a standard COM object from your VB6 projects.

My knowledge of Access is probably a bit dated and biased by bad experiences, but within reason I would try most other options before resorting to the Access route.

Comment: .net interop is a good idea.  I didn't think of that.  Thanks.

Comment: No problems.  You have an additional performance hit with a COM wrapper on each method call.  But if you design the methods so that you can call them just once or twice, rather then, for example, every iteration in a loop, performance can still be quite good.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered [SQL Server 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/) (as oppose to SQL Server CE)?

1)  Personally, I found that most times that Access DBs corrupted it was due to code that didn't clean up after it self, or there was a faulty Network card involved.

2)

```
string connectionString = @“Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + 
                          @"Data Source = C:\data\northwind.mdb; " +
                          @"User Id = guest; Password = abc123”


using (OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection())
{
    oleDbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    oleDbConnection.Open();

    ...
}
```

3) SQL Server 2008 Express Edition

Comment: warning - Microsoft come out with a new and different Mobile database every three or four years.

Comment: Are you saying that you can edit SQL for Access with the  SQL Server 2008 Express Edition?

Answer (score 4):

MDB corruption is largely due to failures that occur in client machines, file servers, and networks while the database is open.  If you put the MDB on a file share this is always a risk, if on a local hard drive and used by one user the problems are much rarer.

I would not expect SQLite to be any different, and if anything worse.

Periodically running JetComp.exe (a Microsoft download) will fix many problems and compact index tables and such.  Backups are important no matter what you use.

You don't need MS Access at all to use Jet MDBs.  There are some 3rd party tools for designing the database schema and doing interactive queries, both command line and GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your point.  I was going to say the same.  All database files face corruption risks.  All database files need an effective backup and recovery option.  Access files are no different.  In this regard their is a downside to access...you can't do live backups.  But it can be made to work in a lot of situations.

Answer (score 2):

Since the MDB format is more or less deprecated, your late 90s knowledge is quite up to date. [See this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx)

Comment: Uh, that article's section on deprecated technologies is about MDAC not so much about using Jet through other interfaces. The article is also wrong about DAO, which has a recent update in A2007.

Comment: That's why I said "more or less", MS seems to have come around a bit. But it's clearly not the DB platform where things are happening.

Comment: A pragmatic stance IMO is that Jet and the .mdb format is deprecated and that ACE and the .accdb format have a future in Access only. More has been removed from the engine (e.g. user level security, replication) than has been put in (multi-value types, anyone?) but that's the price for progress :)

Comment: ACE format provides stronger encryption as well.  There has been an ACE Provider for use via ADO for some time now.  Even so Jet is far from dead, and it does still offer replication and user/group security.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [SQL Anywhere](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1016644) it runs on various OS and has a small footprint. Works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

AngryHacker asked:

Q1. Have they resolved the problem where the database would corrupt every now and then.

Er, what?

There was never any corruption problem in properly engineered apps properly deployed in properly maintained environments. I haven't seen a corrupted MDB in 3 or 4 years, and I have dozens of my apps in full-time production use by many clients in many different types of operating environments.

I think that most people who experience corruption are those who try to share an MDB file among many users (whether split or unsplit). Since you're not contemplating using Access, that's not really an issue.

Q2. Is access to the MDB from c# accomplished via the ADO.NET OLEDB Provider or is there a native solution (i can't seem to find it).

The native solution would be DAO, but that's COM, so you might not want to use that. From C#, I'd say OLEDB is your best bet, but that's not my area of expertise so take it with a grain of salt. I believe that Michael Kaplan reported that the Jet ADO/OLEDB provider was thread-safe, while DAO is not. This doesn't mean he recommended ADO/OLEDB over DAO, though, but his comments also came in an Access context, and not C#.

Q3. Is there a viable alternative to the really crappy SQL Editor in Access?

Why would you be using that when you're not actually using Access? You could use any SQL editor you like as long as you test that the SQL you write is compatible with Jet's SQL dialect.

I, for one, don't see what the issue is with Access's SQL editor (other than the inability to set the font size), but then, I write a lot of my SQL using the QBE and don't ever even look at the SQL view.

Comment: "Why would you be using that when you're not actually using Access?" Er, what? To be able to assess the SQL Editor in Access as being crappy then surely they must be using Access?!

Comment: I don't think Access has a SQL editor as such; rather, it has a GUI query builder that has a SQL view. Take a look at an online SQL formatter (http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) and the degree to which it can be customized. Access has no comparable features :(

Comment: I've never missed those features, myself.

Comment: "I've never missed those features" -- how could you miss something you've never used?! You don't write your own SQL, you get the QBE to write it for you, right?

Comment: I almost never use QBE in Access.  If my query is short, it's easy enough to write the SQL.  And if my query is very complex, QBE can't handle it.  And I write a lot of ridiculously complex sql.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question regarding the really crappy SQL editor in Access - I wholeheartedly agree.  The font stinks, MSAccess always badly reformats the query, it sometimes adds in metacharacters that break my SQL, and lastly but worstly, if it can't parse the SQL, it won't let you have access to it!

My solution is to use external code.  I use DAO to instantiate MSAccess and can then directly edit the queries using the QueryDefs collection.  It lets you do most things - create, rename, edit, etc.  There are a couple of things you cannot do this way though - for example, you do not have access to the query metadata (description, hidden, etc).

External code is also great because you can build a suite of test cases, specifying expected return values, etc.